# How can I do to test the method save from a Model?

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I have this model :

```
class Team(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="default", null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

And I would like to do a unittest for the save.

I have that :

```
class TeamModelTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        Team.objects.create(user='Peter')

    def test_save(self):
        team = Team()
        team.user = 'Bruce'
        team.save()
```

But the problem is how can I do to test a function which return nothing ?

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You could re-fetch the object from the DB and check that it is indeed updated.

```
def test_save(self):
    // arrange
    team = Team()
    team.user = 'Bruce'

    // act
    team.save()

    // assert
    team_from_db = Team.objects.get(id=team.id)
    // assert that team_from_db.user == "Bruce"...
```